# Cannot skip CSRF security for controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf, mandrill, csrf-protection

I want to disable CSRF security for one controller. My ApplicationController looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

And controller where i want to skip:

```
class HelpdeskInboxController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication

  include Mandrill::Rails::WebHookProcessor
  authenticate_with_mandrill_keys! MANDRILL_CONFIG['WEBHOOKS']
```

And it isn't working i've got error

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

When mandrill sends me an email.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` will only work with rails 4. Try `skip_before_filter` instead.